# How do I print a list of commits with branch names for EVERY commit in git?

Tags: git

I would like to print the git log so that EVERY commit is printed with the branch(es) it is in.

I tried using various versions of git log but none of them print the branch name with EVERY commit.

```
git log --author=user   --all --decorate --oneline
git log --pretty='%Cblue%h%C(cyan)%d%Cred %cn %Cgreen %ar %Creset %s'
git log --pretty=format':%h  [%an] %s%d' --graph --date=short --all --date-order
git log --pretty=format':%h  [%an] %s%d\' --graph --date=short --all --date-order
git log --pretty=format':\"%h  [%an] %s%d\' --graph --date=short --all --date-order
git log --pretty=format:\"%h  [%an] %s%d\" --graph --date=short --all --date-order
git log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad [%an] %s%d\" --graph --date=short --all --date-order
```

I understand that branches in git are just pointers to commits and a particular commit could belong to multiple branches.

Answer (score 3):

Git does not have anything built-in to do this.

A very slow but simple method is to use `git rev-list` to get the same commit IDs that `git log` would show, then run `git log --no-walk --pretty=tformat:'...'` (tformat adds a newline, you could include an explicit newline instead) on each such ID with the format including the branch names obtained from `git branch --contains`:

```
for sha1 in $(git rev-list --all --date-order); do
    # season below to taste, this is very primitive
    contains=$(echo $(git branch --all --contains $sha1 | sed 's/^..//'))
    git log --pretty=tformat:"%h [%an] %s ($contains)" --no-walk $sha1
done
```

You'll probably want something more clever and/or faster, but that's harder to code up.

(Note that with `--all` you get remote branches, and if `remotes/origin/HEAD` is an indirect branch you will get `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` in `$contains` here.)